Twikit library returning a 400 when trying to login
I'm working with Twikit to get some data from the Twitter website. However, I encountered the following error when I tried to log into the account I created to do this project.
This is the error:
twikit.errors.BadRequest: status: 400, message: "{"errors":[{"code":366,"message":"flow name LoginFlow is currently not accessible"}]}"

I've tried using a different account and deleting the cookies on my machine. But nothing has worked for me.
This is my code so far:
import os
import os.path

from dotenv import load_dotenv
import asyncio
import csv

load_dotenv()

# Import credentials
USERNAME = os.getenv("USERNAME")
PASSWORD = os.getenv("PASSWORD")
EMAIL = os.getenv("EMAIL")

client = Client("en-US")

async def login():
   await client.login(
       auth_info_1=USERNAME,
       auth_info_2=EMAIL,
       password=PASSWORD
   )


async def search_and_download(key_word):
   query = f"{key_word} lang:en -login -support since:2023-01-01 until:2024-10-01"
   
   tweets = await client.search_tweet(
       query=query
   )

   # Save tweets in csv file
   file_path = 'files/raw/twitter/tweets.csv'
   file_exists = os.path.isfile(file_path)

   with open(file_path, mode='a', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
       writer = csv.writer(file)
       if not file_exists:
           writer.writerow(['id', 'user', 'text', 'created_at'])

       # Process and save tweets
       print(f"Downloading tweets for: {key_word}...")
       for tweet in tweets:
           writer.writerow([tweet.id, tweet.user.name, tweet.text, tweet.created_at])

   print(f"Tweets saved for keyword: {key_word}")


async def main():
   await login()

   # Group similar key words and include sentiment-related terms
   key_words_files = ["binance_trends.csv", "bitcoin_trends.csv",  "cardano_trends.csv",  "crypto_trends.csv",  "ethereum_trends.csv"]
   key_words = []

   for file in key_words_files:
       with open("keywords/"+ file, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
           reader = csv.reader(file)
           for row in reader:
               key_words.append(row[0])
   
   key_words = [kw for kw in key_words if kw not in ["keywords", ""]]

   # Additional sentiment-related terms
   sentiment_terms = [
       "profit", "loss", "bullish", "bearish", "crash", "rise", "sell-off", "moon", "panic"
   ]

   # Group key words with sentiment-related terms
   extended_key_words = []
   for kw in key_words:
       for sentiment in sentiment_terms:
           extended_key_words.append(f"{kw} {sentiment}")
       extended_key_words.append(kw)

   # Search and download tweets for every key word with sentiment context
   for key_word in extended_key_words:
       await search_and_download(key_word, "Latest")


if __name__ == "__main__":
   asyncio.run(main())

Any suggestions to fix this?
Also, this code worked before without any issues. This problem started a couple of days ago.

Seems to be related with the user_agent: https://github.com/d60/twikit/issues/196#issuecomment-2323123750
